# Union vs Insert Into [temp table]

Tags: sql-server, union, temp-tables, insert-into

I had a simple stored procedure that used 6 unions to build a report with same number of rows/headings etc which I pulled into Power BI to build a set of reports/Charts over.
This took around 10 mins to run which in the world of Power BI wasn't really on.

So I decided to try another approach and use a #temporary table using INSERT INTO.

This may be much faster however I am getting the same error message on 4 of the the INSERT INTO lines.

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 68 [Line 79, Line 101, Line 112]
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Why would this be, I do not get it when I use UNION

Martin

Comment: Because one of the columns is not large enough to hold that values being inserted. Maybe you have 100 characters in your data and you are inserting into a varchar(50).

Comment: You are so right, I found that when I generated the temp table table by scripting the destination table then worked flawlessly. 975 row out put taking 5 minutes still seems like a long time even with Keys and Indexes